# Actionscript externalinterface can access parent dom id?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I would like to know if from an swf I can access parent dom id container.

I explain better. I have an swf loaded in a page in a div:

```
<div class="text-center" id="data24">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="Base" name="Base" align="middle"      data="http://www.tropical.seo:8888/includes/assets/Base.js" width="80" height="28"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></object>
</div>
```

From my swf with external interface class can I

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)  
{  
    ExternalInterface.call("fromAS");  
}
```

and in fromAS javascript function output the div of the container? data24 in this case...

[EDIT]

I need a way to get the id of the div container from inside the actionscript if I don't know what the div name is...

Comment: Have you tried it? ;) (Hint: if you do, it should work)

Comment: Very useful!!! I've tried to console.log(this) and the output is the window ogject...

Comment: Yeah, normal JS/DOM stuff applies... document.getElementById('mySWF') or $('#mySWF') with jQuery...

Comment: Probably I do not explain well: I need a way to access the parent element from the swf

Comment: I don;t think you really can. Or you need to know in JS what the parent is already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExternalInterface.objectId](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#objectID) gives you the ID of the HTML element displaying the SWF. Use it to access the SWF element and through it, the parent node.

```
var getParent:String = 'function (objectId) { return document.getElementById(objectId).parentNode.id; }';

if (ExternalInterface.available)
    trace(ExternalInterface.call(getParent, ExternalInterface.objectID));
```